# dataframe panda row information

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rows, nan

[image]

I have been searching the pandas information and can't seem locate any information.

Here is what I am trying to do - I am in trying to explore data I got using pandas. I have dataframe below:

```
        michael   larry  Moe Carol 
height  NaN       5'8''  6'   5'3"
weight  150       230   NaN   60 
eyes    NaN       NaN   NaN   blue 
hair    black     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

This is simplification but I will have 50 rows and hundreds of columns

I want be able to count the number of `NaN` or missing data per row. I want to basically say we are i.e. we are missing 75% of `eyes` information, 25% of `height` information, etc..

I have tried basic commands like 
df.isnull().sum(axis=1) 
which I believe should give me count via rows but it is all zero- which doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: are the `NaN` values truly NaN or those are strings? I am asking cause I have recreated your example and it looks like the command that you proposed is returning correct values. For NaNs I used `numpy.NaN`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I converted a dictionary within dictionary to dataframe and it has for value 'NaN'. It is string then. Do know what I can do convert in order for command to work?

Comment: I think that this should do the job: `df.replace(to_replace="NaN", value=np.NaN)` (assuming, that numpy is imported as np). And a link to 
[doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for more info :)

Comment: Thanks. I ran the command and performed the command I still get zero for NaN count or sum.

Comment: Just to be sure that we do not look in wrong place, have you assigned the result of the command to a variable, like `df = df.replace(to_replace="NaN", value=np.NaN)`? I'm asking, cause at the very first try I forgot about this and was wondering what is going on.

Comment: I doubled by running df.isnull() it is treating the NaN values as NaN instead of string and it is has correct count or sum. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, cool, good to hear that is working. Happy coding! :)